# Error type while using List.fold_left

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, typeerror

There is a type error with this code, if you guys help me that will be great...

```
29  let function_1 func (accu: 'a list) b = if (func b)    (* func is a function that takes in a value and returns a boolean*)
30                                        then accu::[]    (* If func return false, I append an empty list. It will create a list list, and it is my intention.*)
31                                        else accu::[b]   (* If func return true, I append the element b.*)
32
33  let function_2 func list =                             (* func is a function that takes in a value and returns a boolean. It is used in function_1*)
34           match list with
35           | [] -> [ [] ]
36           | x::rest -> List.fold_left function_1 func [x] rest
```

The error is at:

```
Line 36, characters 29-40
Error: This expression has type
          ('a list -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list list
       but an expression was expected of type
          ('a list -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> bool
       Type 'a list list is not compatible with type bool
```

P.S. If you may, please give me explanation instead of actual code. I am more interested in how to debug this and why it doesn't work......

Thanks!

Comment: A good start would be naming your functions something more meaningful than `function_1`, `function_2` and `func`. That would greatly help others understand what you're trying to do, in order to be able to help you

Comment: Also, annotating the types of the functions would be helpful both to us, to the compiler, and even to you. You might even be able to solve it yourself once you have the types in place and a better udnerstanding of where they don't match up correctly.

Comment: One issue I found just based on your descriptive comments, and that would have been caught by a type annotation: `accu::[]`  doesn't mean that you append an empty list to the `accu` list. It means you're appending the `accu` element (which happens to be a list) to an empty list. The result being a list of lists.

Comment: @glennsl Thanks for helping. I believe my code for `function_1` is correct. The only difficulty I have right now is that I cannot figure out what is causing this type error...

Comment: If you follow my suggestion of naming and annotating the types of the functions, you'll help both us and yourself by clarifying your intention and allowing us to help you. Right now it's not clear what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `List.fold_left` is `('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`, so
the return type of the function that you pass to `fold_left` (in your case it's `function_1`) must be the same as his first argument. But the type of `function_1` is `('a list -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list list` and not `('a list -> bool) -> 'a list -> ('a list -> bool)`.

I do not know what you are trying to achieve, so I can't say too much.